# How to setup a rails app as a DDP server to serve collections to a meteor app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meteor, ddp

I have a rails app with some collections that I want to setup up as the source for the collections on a meteor app.

which from my understanding I can connect to from meteor by doing so.

```
var remote = DDP.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');
Customers = new Meteor.Collection('customers', remote); 

remote.subscribe('customers', function() {
  var customers = Customers.find();
  console.log(customers.count());       
});
```

that seems pretty simple for the meteor part, however I have been having trouble trying to figure out how to take rails model and expose it as a publication.

I found the ruby-ddp-client here https://github.com/knubie/ruby-ddp-client
and also looked at the example given here http://www2.bindle.me/blog/index.php/726/augmenting-meteor-plugging-gaps-with-external-services and i still dont understand how to just expose a simple rails model using the above examples.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your gem `ruby-ddp-client`, it`s a DDP ***client*** so you only can ***consume*** the data from a ddp-server (like meteor) with your rails app. So you only could push data to meteor or read it with rails.

If you really need rails as a `ddp-server` you may have to spend some time to create a ddp server for rails on your own.